# Jquery ajax error callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need some suggestions here or maybe some explanations. I have a jquery ajax call,

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: base_url+'/ajax/fetch/counts/',
 dataType: 'json',
 data: {},
 error: function(xhr, error){
        console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
 },
 success: display_counts
});
```

It's working fine. My `success` callback fires correctly with response. But, what I noticed is that my `error` callback is fired every time, even when my call returns success status 200. In the above `error` callback, I see that object `xhr.status` is 200.

Can anybody explain what's wrong, or what is happening here? `error` callback is supposed to fire only when I have 404 or maybe a non-200 response. Are my assumptions correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Error callback is called on http errors, but also *if JSON parsing on the response fails*. This is what's probably happening if response code is 200 but you still are thrown to error callback.

Comment: If you are expecting a non JSON response. You can set the dataType option to script/text...etc Checkout http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax and look under dataFilter for more information.

Comment: I was calling a cgi script, I needed it to dump out the data in json format. It was returning a string which failed.

Answer (score 39):

Just an suggestion, try using the [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to get the correct error like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just as an aside, [the Docs state](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/): *Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective global Ajax event handler methods—.ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(), .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(), .ajaxSuccess(), .ajaxSend()—rather than within the options object for $.ajaxSetup().* so it would seem that this would be better used in [`.ajaxError()`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

Comment: So an important thing to realize of course is that your ajax could fail on a user's computer if their internet connection is spotty. So your app could be working fine but they get failed ajax requests because of a bad internet connection - which appears to be identifiable by the `status === 0` and `exception === 'timeout'` cases above.

Comment: Also note that docs state that: "This can cause undesirable behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting the normal default settings. For that reason we *strongly recommend against using this API.*"

Answer (score 2):

A [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639317/jquery-whats-up-with-the-success/3639725#3639725) had similar problem with `json` jquery requests, try removing surrounding `()` from your json response.

Comment: Funny, I've had a similar problem that was fixed by *adding* surrounding brackets.

Comment: @Coronatus Yes, this what I usually used to do, but jquery 1.4.2 starts to rely on browser's `JSON.parse`, my firefox's `JSON.parse` would parse `{"key":"value"}` successfully, but issue an error on `({"key":"value"})`.

Comment: To get around the differences in which browsers parse JSON, I would recommend using Douglas Crockford's parser: http://www.json.org/json2.js

Answer (score 2):

A few things I can think of:

1. Make sure you have disabled caching by setting `cache: false`.
2. If you are using Firefox, try using Firebug and the Net tab to monitor the request
3. Don't rely on the browser's JSON parser. I would recommend this one: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js from the creator of JSON no less

Comment: "trivial and obvious" - well, that was simply harsh. :)

Comment: Well sorry if that was really harsh. +1 already for referring to JSON parser thing. :)

Comment: @SimpleCoder
"Don't rely on the browser's JSON parser"??
why?
is it the same for now??

Comment: @mfadel: Some older browsers don't support JSON, so using a third-party parser in the first-place could prevent compatibility headaches.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a jQuery expert, but I know that bwith Prototype.js, the AJAX error handler fires if the request is successful but the `success` handler causes an an error. Is that the same in jQuery? You could test if this is what's happening by putting the entire contents of `display_counts` in a [try..catch block](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp).

Answer (score -1):

Change `dataType` from `plain/text` to `html`

Comment: ...but OP doesn't even have plain/text dataType