# AJAX failing silently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a problem with one of my AJAX requests. All of this was working earlier, then I moved some files around in folders, and it must have broken something, but I have been unable to figure out what may be wrong with my pathing.

**What is happening**

AJAX request seems to be being ignored, nothing goes to console or the network tab, responseText is "", and I put a break point in the first line of the PHP which is never hit.  It goes straight from `$.ajax` to the first line in my error callback. Additionally, when this PHP code is called by going straight to the page, or cron, it works fine.

I have a very similar call later to another file in the same folder that is working just fine.

**What I have tried**

As mentioned before, I have looked at responseText, console output, network tab, and breakpoints in my PHP (which are never reached), and I have looked around Google and stackoverflow. If I intentionally change the name to a non-existing file, I promptly get an error in the console.

Code below

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PHP/myFile.php",
        data: '',
        success: function () {
            //Success code
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            var response = xhr.responseText; // response is ""
            //Error code
        }
    });
```

Any ideas?

Here is the code, later in the file, which (successfully) grabs code from a file in the same folder.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: "PHP/myOtherFile.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // Success code
        },
        error: function () {
            // Error Code
        }
    });
```

Pretty basic AJAX calls, not sure what is going on :/

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: And in your php file? What's going on?

Comment: what are the values of the other two parameters passed to the error callback?

Comment: Did you check you console what error does it give you.

Comment: FYI, per [jQuery.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), "the .fail() method replaces the deprecated .error() method."

Comment: can u put console.log(xhr.status); into the error function?

Comment: @Neal, nothing in the console at all

Comment: Are you missing datatype?

Comment: @Jordan in the network tab?

Comment: @Neal "nothing goes to console or the network tab"

Comment: @PhilNicholas he isn't even using `.error`

Comment: @dscdsc It xhr.status gives me 0

Comment: @j08691 ahhh did not see that for some reason.

Comment: Remove `data: '',` and try with `type: "GET"`. You are not passing anything, does not need to be post nor have the data attribute.

Comment: I see you're doing a POST. If you call the url via browser you do a GET. Be sure if your php script is correct with a POST

Comment: Please clarify a few things. Are you getting to the error callback? What are the values of the three parameters passed to the error callback? (should be an object, a statuscode, and a jQuery error message). So far it sounds like either a server error or a pathing issue. there's nothing wrong with the jQuery code you have provided.

Comment: Lot of comments O.o, trying to keep up, I removed the `data: ''` line, and I am 99% certain my php is fine with a post (considering I don't even actually post any parameters for it to use), as this has been working the last few weeks.

Comment: @KevinB Hey Kevin, yes, I am getting to the error callback, and aren't the statuscode and error message the same as `xhr.status` and `xhr.responseText`? If so, they are `0` and `""` respectively. I agree with the pathing issue, I just don't see how that is possible when it works fine with the other file, which is located in the same place (PHP folder)

Comment: the status yes, but not the jquery error text, though it might end up being "" if jQuery can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Status code 0 mean no network connectivity generally. Can you look into that, i know its the least probably thing.

Comment: @chumkiu Bizarrely, changing it to a GET actually makes it work, even though it has been working with POST for a few weeks. Any idea why changing file structure would cause this?

Comment: Do you use an .htaccess file? If so can you post it?

Comment: Try using error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... }

Comment: either firewall or htaccess file needs to be checked, it could be worthwhile moving the file to another folder and check again

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you guys. I changed it to a GET to see if that worked as chumkiu suggested, which worked. Then, I changed it back to a POST to check the error textStatus and errorThrown, and... it worked. Changed nothing else, just POST, to GET, and back to POST O.o

Comment: @Jordan totally depends of your php file. Maybe there is some line that break something on POST

Comment: Boooooo, what a boring solution. Such a letdown ;)

Comment: Sorry @j08691 ;) If it makes you feel better, I am a little letdown as well, was kind of hoping to figure out what actually was causing this.

Comment: @Jordan Someone earlier in the comments suggested a status of 0 means network connectivity issues.  That would completely explain why it continued to work - you just hit a blip in the network that resolved itself

Comment: @Izkata I saw that, but wouldn't that have caused my other AJAX to fail? I first was attempting to fix this before lunch, then went out to lunch to stew on it, and the issue was still there (only for this ajax request) Seems like a network issue wouldn't make sense. Unless of course I am thinking about it incorrectly :P

Comment: Please copy the AJAX BASE code I made and replace with your stuff and check what you are actually receiving: http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/HAzbF/ (of course copy to your project, ajax will fail from jsfiddle for urls that don't return jsonp).

Answer (score 1):

> Error callback is called on http errors, but **also if JSON parsing on
>   the response fails**

From: [Jquery ajax error callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642348/jquery-ajax-error-callback)

From your working file, the code `dataType: 'json'` im blindly assuming your doing some kind of json parsing.
Try just making the "myFile.php" a simple `echo 'x';` script, and check the response text. If your get something, then its because your script contains JSON parsing code, but your not passing any data to the script anyways.

Hence, the error callback would be called because the script is trying to JSON parse nothing (i.e. `data: ''`)

I cant suggest anything else, from reading your questions description, hopefully someone else figures it out. goodluck

Comment: Both files are working now, but the one which was being a problem actually did not have any kind of json parsing, just database manipulations. Thank you for taking the time to give it some thought however!