# Update Database Record with Ajax in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to update database records using ajax from the ajax response, getting success message but the actual database records are not updated at all. But it wonder how the ajax response should throw the success message while the query is not updating the database.

**VIEW:**

```js
// AJAX code to update the database
// update marks when form is submitted 
$('#updateMarks').on('submit',function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var practical_mark = $("#mark_written").val();
  var written_mark   = $("#mark_practical").val(); 
  var comment        = $("#comment").val();
  var mark_id        = $("#mark_id").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/exam_marks_update'); ?>",
    data: { practical_mark : practical_mark, 
           written_mark: written_mark, 
           comment : comment,
           mark_id : mark_id
          },
    success: function(response)
    {
      alert("success");
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Error");
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<?php foreach($marks as $row2): ?>
<form method="post" role="form" id="updateMarks">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><?php echo $student['name']; ?></td>
    <td>
      <!-- create two col table for marks category -->
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover toggle-circle">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th data-toggle="true" class="text-center"><?php echo get_phrase('written_exam'); ?></th>
            <th data-toggle="true" class="text-center"><?php echo get_phrase('practical_exam'); echo get_phrase('_(out_of_100)'); ?></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="number" value="<?php echo $row2['written_mark_obtained'];?>" id="mark_written" name="mark_written" class="form-control"  /></td>
            <td class="text-center"><input type="number" value="<?php echo $row2['practical_mark_obtained'];?>" id="mark_practical" name="mark_practical" class="form-control"/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- end create two col table for marks category -->
    </td>
    <td class="text-center"><textarea class="form_control" id="comment" name="comment" rows="4" > <?php echo $row2['comment'] ?> </textarea></td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="hidden" id="mark_id" name="mark_id" value="<?php echo $row2['mark_id'];?>" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-md"><i class="icon pe-pen" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php echo get_phrase('update'); ?></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Controller:**

```html
function exam_marks_update(){
$data['written_mark_obtained']   = $this->input->post('written_mark');
$data['practical_mark_obtained'] = $this->input->post('practical_mark');
$data['comment']                 = $this->input->post('comment');
$this->crud_model->update_student_marks($data, $this->input->post('mark_id'));
}
```

**MODEL**

```html
function update_student_marks($data, $mark_id){
$this->db->where('mark_id', $mark_id);
$this->db->update('mark', $data);
}
```

Comment: Use inspect element , fire bug for  ajax request errors if any.

Comment: there seems no error while i inspect the element .. i am using chrome browser and when i click update button it shows the success message but doesn't update the db :(

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller retrieving inputs which doesn't exists... you need to pass your `name, id` as inputs and not the value which you echo... see as Controller:

```
function exam_marks_update(){
$data = array(
    'written_mark_obtained'   => $this->input->post('written_mark'),
    'practical_mark_obtained' => $this->input->post('practical_mark'),
    'comment'                 => $this->input->post('comment')
);
$this->db->where('mark_id', $this->input->post('mark_id'));
$this->db->update('mark', $data);
}
```

and change this:

```
  var comment        = $("#comment").val();
```

to

```
  var comment        = $("#comment").html();
```

As comment is textarea...

Comment: You mean i have to set the parameter to the controller function ??

Comment: @sujandahal i meant u wrote the wront input  names.. just try my controller it will work

Comment: I am trying your controller but no good luck for me :( any other solutions ??
i am also set my form inside foreach loop which is the reason for this issue ?? because the update button is just working for the first row retrieved through foreach

Comment: so how can i pass the input values to ajax and ajax to controller. if you can mention it clearly with code then it will great help for me

Comment: @sujandahal yes without the model just do as my code now

Comment: which shows the success message but unfortunately the db velues remains the same .. it doesn't changed  .. Is my ajax function has any code that doesn't send the data array to controller

Comment: @sujandahal when html is loaded open up the source code and check "<?php echo site_url('admin/exam_marks_update'); ?>", does it print the correct path to the ajax?? becuase the code is just fine

Comment: @sujandahal and alsot see my edit. use .html() on textarea not .val()

Comment: my actual path defines by ? means my URL looks like `http://localhost/vidya/index.php?admin/exam_marks` but using `<?php echo site_url('admin/exam_marks_update'); ?>` displays the `http://localhost/vidya/index.php/admin/exam_marks` and when i paste this on my URL bar it redirects me to dashboard as my default controller which is loaded if the user is logged in ..

Answer (score 0):

Jquery ajax `success` callback function is always called if the request to server succeeds. You need to return response data from server to verify when database operation was successful or not.  I have edited your code , this might work for you.

MODEL

```
 function update_student_marks($data, $mark_id){
      .....
      return $this->db->update('mark', $data);
    }
```

Controller::

```
  function exam_marks_update(){
      .....
      if($this->crud_model->update_student_marks($data, $this->input->post('mark_id'))){
       echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
       exit;
     } else {
      echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
      exit;
    }
 }
```

View

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/exam_marks_update'); ?>",
        dataType :'json',
        data: { practical_mark : practical_mark, 
               written_mark: written_mark, 
               comment : comment,
               mark_id : mark_id
              },
        success: function(response)
        {
          if (response.success === true){
            alert("success");
          } else {
            alert('failed');
          }
        },
        error: function(){
          alert("Error");
        },
      });
```

Comment: Now it shows the error message but how it will possible to find from where error message is actually belong.

Comment: did it alert failed alert('failed');  ?

Comment: No it shows the Error from the actual error function

Comment: try this error: function(ts) { alert(ts.responseText);  }

Comment: you can also check http status , error: function(ts) { alert(ts.status); }

Comment: it throws the number '200'

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642348/jquery-ajax-error-callback this might help you.

Comment: I am new to ajax and i don't even understand the whole part but i think the JSON parsing on the response fails is the main reason .. if you have any idea for resolving the issue it will be great help for me. :)